# NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100 in Swift 4

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection

I want to open the given url in webview without https (Example myDomain.com). I get the

> NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100

error for swift opening url on Android. How can I do it?

```
let url = URL(string: "myDomain.com")

webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
```

Comment: Why without https?

Comment: They told me to do it this way. Is there any solution?

Comment: Yes, with https (or http). Have you tried?

Comment: No, I don't this

Answer (score 5):

Apple doesn't allow plain HTTP requests anymore, as of WWDC 2015. However you can disable this restriction. You will need to add this to your `Info.plist` file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

(To open the file as source code, just right-click it and choose "Open As")

Comment: I just checked, error code -1100 means that the file at the URL you specified does not exist. So you must be using a wrong URL. See here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlerrorfiledoesnotexist